# Symfony Exception Subscriber not triggered

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I need to format error messages and output it in JSON format.

I have the following event subscriber:

```php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

final class ExceptionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => 'onKernelException'];
    }

    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event) {/*..*/}
}
```

And following configuration in `./config/services.yaml`

```yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    App\EventSubscriber\ExceptionSubscriber:
        tags:
            - {name: kernel.event_subscriber, event: kernel.exception}
```

---

This event subscriber is working when e.g. controller throws error.

But if I have some other error e.g. wrong DI injection

```php
class FooBar {
    public __constructor(NonExistingService $service) {/*..*/}
}
```

then output is still in Html format and as Symfony error page.

---

How to make that any error that Symfony catches is converted via my class to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what's wrong here.

Problem is that if you have e.g. configuration error, your events will be not yet hooked up.

In my code I have this:

```php
// index.php

if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
    umask(0000);

    $errorHandler = Debug::enable();
}

$kernel = new Kernel();
/* .. */
```

This `Debug::enable()` actually sets error handler (without that there is only PHP default error handler at start).

I have extended `Debug` with my own class:

```php
namespace App\Error;

use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\BufferingLogger;
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Debug as SymfonyDebug;
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler;

class Debug extends SymfonyDebug
{
    public static function enable(): ErrorHandler
    {
        if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
            umask(0000);

            $errorHandler = parent::enable();
        }

        return self::setDefaultErrorHandler($errorHandler ?? null);
    }

    private static function setDefaultErrorHandler(?ErrorHandler $errorHandler): ErrorHandler
    {
        $errorHandler ??= ErrorHandler::register(new ErrorHandler(new BufferingLogger(), true));

        $errorHandler->setExceptionHandler([ExceptionHandler::class, 'renderException']);

        return $errorHandler;
    }
}
```

---

Now all errors goes through my `App\Error\ExceptionHandler` where I can output it as `JsonResponse`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're referring to, but make sure you're setting the response correctly:

```
    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event): void
    {
        $exception = $event->getThrowable();

        $response = new JsonResponse(
            ['error'],
            Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.api+json',
            ]
        );

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
```

Comment: `onKernelException` is not even called. First sentence there is `echo "OK"; die();`

Comment: The Symfony docs state that `The TwigBundle registers an Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener that forwards the Request to a given controller defined by the exception_listener.controller parameter.`. Maybe it has something to do with that subscriber? https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-exception

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default error controller in configuration.

Check the docs here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-errorcontroller